# Sort rows by a specific column containing numbers

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

How to sort rows by a column containing numbers in ascending or descending order?
I know how to sort using Filters and Using Sort function in VBA. But it sorts in alphabetical order only not by numbers.

This is so far I have done.But still the sorting is coming alphabetically.

```
Sub sortdata()
Dim LastRow As Integer

NoOfRows = Sheets("RawData").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("RawData").Rows("2:" & NoOfRows).NumberFormat = "0"
    Sheets("RawData").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RawData").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:B" & NoOfRows)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide an example of the data you are trying to sort and what you are seeing, because Excel does indeed sort numbers.

Comment: I will provide an example . If the column A contains this values:1,2,55,12,14,5343,22222,9 Then after sorting using filter or inbuilt sort method. The values are sorted as follows:1,12,14,2,22222,5343,9. But I need the result as follows: 1,2,9,12,14,5334,22222. Is there any in-built function for this?

Comment: ok. yes the sort function does sort alphabetically and the result is correct in this case. you need to implement your own (or use someones)  sort algorithm

Comment: I just read your most recent comment.  The problem is that your numbers are stored as text.  You'll need to convert them to numbers.  Select column A -> Data -> Text to Columns -> Finish

Comment: To those who down voted my question. Was this a stupid question? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the Range.Sort method:

[EDIT 2]:
I have added the .TextToColumns line to programmatically address the numbers stored as text issue

```
Sub sortdata()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("RawData")

    With ws.Range("A1:B" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        Intersect(.Cells, ws.Columns("A")).TextToColumns
        .Sort Intersect(.Cells, ws.Columns("A")), xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
    End With

End Sub
```

[EDIT]:
After reading asker's comment:

> I will provide an example . If the column A contains this
>   values:1,2,55,12,14,5343,22222,9 Then after sorting using filter or
>   inbuilt sort method. The values are sorted as
>   follows:1,12,14,2,22222,5343,9. But I need the result as follows:
>   1,2,9,12,14,5334,22222. Is there any in-built function for this?

The problem is that your numbers are stored as text. You'll need to convert them to numbers.

Select column A -> Data -> Text to Columns -> Finish

Now the numbers should sort correctly.

Comment: Doesn't this sort alphabetically?

Comment: It would sort ascending on column A, and cells in column B would be kept with their corresponding cells in column A.  So if column A was numbers, it would sort those numbers in ascending order

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to know the difference between number format and text to column

Comment: Number format changes how a cell displays its value.  Text to columns converts text to appropriate values and splits text from one column to several columns if appropriate.  Some experimenting, reading the Excel help, or googling should provide all the information you need.